# why the multiplication between functionals is not well defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, infinite-groups, poisson-geometry

I'm reading [Olver (2012)](https://books.google.com/books?hl=es&lr=&id=qC_oBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR15&dq=olver&ots=UD5dAiVAr0&sig=u5lEqfDVIyfjL9Y9pYgLSZFL1Y8), chapter 7, and it says that the multiplication between functionals is not well defined. Then he refers to the section 5.4 where gives an explanation why, but I can't understand it.

Why I'm doing this question? well, I'm wondering why the notion of a Poisson bracket on the finite-dimensional setting drop off the Leibniz rule, see [Kolev (2007)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.1412.pdf). In section 3.3 when is defining a Hamiltonian Structure(A Poisson Structure but in functional spaces) it says that there is no well defined multiplication in functional spaces.

Somebody understand why the Hamiltonian structures(as Poisson Structures on infinite-dimensinal setting) drop out the Leibniz rule?

I'm wondering if it has something to do with ["Sur l’impossibilité de la multiplication des distributions"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Sur+l%E2%80%99impossibilit%C3%A9+de+la+multiplication+des+distributions&btnG=) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In this context "the" multiplication refers to a naive one [Olver, §5.4, p. 356]:

> For example, the differential functions $u_x$ and $u_{xxx}$ both determine trivial functionals: $\int u_x dx = 0 = \int u_{xxx} dx$, but their product $u_xu_{xxx}$ is *not* a divergence, and hence $\mathscr{L} = \int u_xu_{xxx} dx$ is not a trivial functional. Indeed, $\delta \mathscr{L} = -2u_{xxxx} \neq 0$, hence by Theorem 4.7, $\mathscr{L} \neq 0$.

Here it is used that $\int D_x(\forall) dx = 0$ (boundary terms are assumed to vanish in this section), $u_x = D_x(u)$, $u_{xxx} = D_x(u_{xx})$, and $\delta \int D_x(\forall)dx = 0$.

The space of functionals $\mathscr{F}$ is defined as the space of differential functions modulo total divergences [loc. cit.], and the quotient map is denoted $L \mapsto \int L dx$. The above shows that there is no induced multiplication on $\mathscr{F}$ because it would depend on the choice of representatives: if such multiplication $\cdot$ were defined, then on the one hand $\int 0 dx \cdot \int 0 dx = \int 0 dx$ by direct computation, but on the other hand $\int 0 dx \cdot \int 0 dx \neq \int 0 dx$ by the example above; this is a contradiction.

Since there is no (such) multiplication, there is no Leibniz rule with respect to it. As noted in [Olver, §7.1 p. 435]:

> However, the principal use of Leibniz' rule was to deduce the existence of a Hamiltonian vector field from a real-valued function $H$. This *does* carry over to the functional case: